# Magento2 import products via csv into multiple categories

Tags: magento2.3, product-import

In Magento2 multistore view website. I have a csv I am trying to import products into the site and identify which categories in each storeview (root category) each product should be in. However it seems to just create some of the categories even though they exist already instead of just adding the products to all the listed categories

As an example in the categories column in on of my rows I have a value like
YD/Color Diamonds, RJ/Color Diamonds

Should I wrap the entire cell in a double quotes or just trying to figure out how it will know the comma is not indicating a separate column and should all be treated as one column cell.

I get an error like

```
Category "RJ/Color Diamonds" has not been created. URL key for specified store already exists.
```

Comment: can you add screenshot of your csv?